# Jenkins File - Multi repo in one pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using `DIR()` to create a directory for multi-repo I checkout. apparently it error out with no meaningful error.

Here is my JenkinsFile snippet

```
try {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "$GIT_CRED"]
                ]) {

      stage ('Checkout LLM')  { 
        try {
         dir('LLMC')
           git poll: true , branch: "${GIT_BRANCH}", credentialsId: "${GIT_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO}"
           echo "checking out"
           sh "ls -l"
           sh "pwd"

        }catch(error) {
              echo "## ERROR- 'Git checkout failed'.exiting"
              sh "exit 1"
              throw error
        }
                        }
```

Error:

```
Running in /home/jenkins/workspace/Dev-Pipelines/LLM-engine/LLMC
[Pipeline] dir
[Pipeline] echo
## ERROR- 'Git checkout failed'.exiting
[Pipeline] sh
[LLM-engine] Running shell script
+ exit 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] echo
## Outer catch caught error. Exiting...
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

It created a new dir and failed while checking out. It works fine with out `dir()` block. How do I enable debug?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by having curly braces with in the dir statement.

```
    try {
     dir('LLMC')
      {
       git poll: true , branch: "${GIT_BRANCH}", credentialsId: "${GIT_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO}"
       echo "checking out"
       sh "ls -l"
       sh "pwd"
      }
    }catch(error) {
```